# Socket.io android socket.on not work after user kill the app

Tags: android, socket.io

I have socket.on in onCreate and it work fine at first.
However, when I kill the app, reopen the app and server receive the message from other person but android socket.on is not working.
But emit function still work. 
Have any suggestion?

### Below is roughly code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.0.0.1/");
        mSocket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    mSocket.on("chat message", onNewMessage);  // not working after kill the app and reopen.

}

private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                String message;
                try {
                    message = data.getString("message");
                    Log.d("message", message );
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return;
                }
        });
    }
};
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mSocket.disconnect();
        mSocket.off("chat message", onNewMessage);
}
```

Android client Socket.io version is socket.io-client:0.7.0.
Server is Node.js and "socket.io": "^1.4.5".

Comment: I have the same problem. following

Comment: Main issue regarding this problem is that, in android there is no callback functionality when application is killed or removed from task because of which Sockets are not getting closed properly. Best approach is to close sockets (mSocket.disconnect())in onPause() callback, but still it depends upon your requirement when to close open sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the problem.
When we kill the app and restart, socket will kill now socket and create a new one. So we have to emit a new event to server to join the original room. And it work fine now.

Comment: Can you please share your final code snippet. I am facing the same issue